# Bluetooth System in MATLAB

Tags: bluetooth, matlab

There is  a  Bluetooth model in MATLAB  that can be accessed  using this command :

```
commbluetoothfduplex
```

Here its Link :
https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/examples/bluetooth-full-duplex-voice-and-data-transmission.html

Also it is shown in the below figure :
[image]

The model can display PSD of the recieved signal before detection which is shown below :
 [image]

As we can see the range extends from 0 till 40 MHz , but it is supposed that the Bluetooth uses the ISM band 2.4 GHz ? So please someone explain this received PSD. Thanks in advance

Comment: Harmonics.  Just because the carrier is at one frequency

Comment: Thank you @JonRB for your reply , but can you please explain it in a little bit more details ?

Comment: I'll repeat what Pipe usually says, @JonRB, that is an answer. Not a comment.

Comment: @harry I agree, I am however on the mobile client (rubbish). I would normally provide full detail answer, especially for matlab-based questions. I might do if I am not too drunk shortly